# Android NDK cannot find -lGLESv

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, android-sdk-tools

I am getting the following errors when I try to perform an NDK build, can anyone help me please?

I did the setup instruction exactly like what are written in "Beginning Android C++ Game Development". every step except the 9th:

> "Click the NativeActivity node in the Application Nodes window and click Add once more. Enter the Name as android.app.lib_name and the Value as the LOCAL_MODULE name, which can be found in the Android.mk file in the project’s jni folder."

Errors :

> 10:44:23 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project
>   HelloDroid **** "C:\ndk\ndk-build.cmd" all  Android NDK:
>   WARNING:jni/Android.mk:HelloDroid-Test: non-system libraries in linker
>   flags: -lGLESv     Android NDK:     This is likely to result in
>   incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES     Android NDK:
>   or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of
>   the     Android NDK:     current module     [armeabi] SharedLibrary  :
>   libHelloDroid-Test.so
>   C:/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe:
>   error: cannot find -lGLESv collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libHelloDroid-Test.so] Error 1
>
> 10:44:23 Build Finished (took 226ms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.
I just needed to edit the Android.mk
it now looks like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := hellodroid
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellodroid.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -landroid -lEGL -lGLESv2
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue 

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module, android/native_app_glue)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, there is no lib `GLESv`.

Which version of OpenGL ES are you using, 1 or 2?

The linker flags are `-lGLESv1_CM` and `-lGLESv2`, respectively.

Comment: I wish to use OpenGL es 2, But I didnt specified anything! and I didnt install anything like Opengl ES on my computer.Meybe I should Instal such thing But how !?